# Sapi how to get elements inside tag elements c++

Tags: sapi

I am working on SAPI 5.4 Here is my one of grammar rule

```
<RULE ID="FIRST_TRANSMISSION" TOPLEVEL="ACTIVE">
    <P><RULEREF REFID="BATTERY"/></P>
    <P><RULEREF REFID="FO"/></P>
    <P><RULEREF REFID="MISSION"/></P>  
</RULE>
```

I used c++ code to get recognized words here is the peace of my code. My rule ID=256

```
case 256:
                {
                    if (SUCCEEDED (hr))
                    {
                        hr = pISpRecoResult->GetText(SP_GETWHOLEPHRASE, SP_GETWHOLEPHRASE, TRUE, &pwszText, NULL);
                    }           

                    char ch[260];
                    char DefChar = ' ';
                    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP,0,pwszText,-1, ch,260,&DefChar, NULL);                       
                    string ss(ch);          
                    str.append(ss);

                    break;
                }
```

Now I want to get recognized words according to sub rules.
ex:- I want to get the recognized word according to `<P><RULEREF REFID="FO"/></P>` this phase in grammar file. How can I do it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [ISpRecoResult::GetPhrase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee450914(v=vs.85).aspx) to retrieve the [SPPHRASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125122(v=vs.85).aspx) associated with the recognition.   Then you can use the `Rule` field of the SPPHRASE to traverse the rules associated with the recognition until you find the one with the id 'FO'.  Once you've found the appropriate SPPHRASERULE, the rule has the word indexes associated with it, and you can call `ISpRecoResult::GetText` as before.

The code would look something like this:  (Note - I haven't actually compiled this, so there are likely going to be errors.)

```
SPPHRASE* pPhrase;
hr = pRecoResult->GetPhrase(&pPhrase);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    ULONG ulFirstElement = 0;
    ULONG ulCountOfElements = 0;
    hr = FindRuleMatching(&pPhrase->Rule, L"FO", &ulFirstElement, &ulCountOfElements);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        LPWSTR pwszText;
        hr = pRecoResult->GetText(ulFirstElement, ulCountOfElements, TRUE, &pwszText, NULL);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
             // do stuff
             ::CoTaskMemFree(pwszText);
        }
    }
    ::CoTaskMemFree(pPhrase);
}


HRESULT
FindRuleMatching(const SPPHRASERULE* pRule, LPCWSTR szRuleName, ULONG* pulFirst, ULONG* pulCount)
{
    if (pRule == NULL)
    {
        return E_FAIL;
    }
    // depth-first search.  
    if (wcscmp(pRule->pszName, szRuleName) == 0)
    {
        *pulFirst = pRule->ulFirstElement;
        *pulCount = pRule->ulCountOfElements;
        return S_OK;
    }
    else if (SUCCEEDED(FindRuleMatching(pRule->pFirstChild, szRuleName, pulFirst, pulCount)))
    {
        return S_OK;
    }
    else return FindRuleMatching(pRule->pNextSibling, szRuleName, pulFirst, pulCount);
}
```